# Coreplot taking forever to render

Tags: ios, objective-c, charts, core-plot

Coreplot is taking an unreasonable amt of time to render. I put logs in all the methods and they all run through quickly. The problem is getting the graph to actually show up in the graphHost. It takes almost a minute every time for less than 400 data points. Code -

```
    -(void)drawChart{

if ( !self.graph ) {
   self.graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.graphHost.frame];
    CPTScatterPlot *priceLinePlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] initWithFrame:self.graph.bounds];
    priceLinePlot.identifier = @"Data Source Plot";
    priceLinePlot.paddingBottom = 0;
    priceLinePlot.paddingTop = 0;
    priceLinePlot.paddingLeft = 0;
    priceLinePlot.paddingRight = 0;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [priceLinePlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
    lineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0;

    int first = [closeTicks.firstObject integerValue];
    int last = [closeTicks.lastObject integerValue];
    int diff = last - first;

    CPTColor *graphColor = (diff >= 0? (CPTColor *)kColorThemeGreen : (CPTColor *)kColorThemeRed);

    lineStyle.lineColor = graphColor;
    priceLinePlot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;
    priceLinePlot.dataSource = self;
    priceLinePlot.delegate = self;
    CPTColor *areaColor1 = graphColor;
    CPTGradient *areaGradient1 = [CPTGradient gradientWithBeginningColor:areaColor1 endingColor:[CPTColor clearColor]];
  //  areaGradient1.angle = -180.0f;
    CPTFill *areaGradientFill = [CPTFill fillWithGradient:areaGradient1];
    priceLinePlot.areaFill = areaGradientFill;
    priceLinePlot.areaBaseValue = [[NSDecimalNumber zero] decimalValue];
    [self.graph addPlot:priceLinePlot];
    priceLinePlot.cachePrecision = CPTPlotCachePrecisionDouble;
    [self.graph applyTheme:nil];
}

self.graphHost.hostedGraph = self.graph;
self.graph.paddingBottom = 0;
self.graph.paddingTop = 0;
self.graph.paddingLeft = 0;
self.graph.paddingRight = 0;

CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)self.graph.defaultPlotSpace;

NSDecimalNumber *high = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:[[closeTicks valueForKeyPath:@"@max.doubleValue"]decimalValue]];
NSDecimalNumber *low  = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:[[closeTicks valueForKeyPath:@"@min.intValue"]decimalValue]];
NSDecimalNumber *length = [high decimalNumberBySubtracting:low];

NSLog(@"high = %@, low = %@, length = %@", high, low, length);
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(xPoints)];
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:[low decimalValue] length:[length decimalValue]];

 // Axes
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)self.graph.axisSet;
CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [axisSet.xAxis.axisLineStyle mutableCopy];
lineStyle.lineWidth = 0.5;
lineStyle.lineColor = (CPTColor *)[UIColor colorWithRed:.9 green:.9 blue:.9 alpha:0.5];
axisSet.xAxis.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;
x.majorIntervalLength         = CPTDecimalFromDouble(1.0);
x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromInteger(0);
x.minorTicksPerInterval       = 0;

CPTXYAxis *y  = axisSet.yAxis;
y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;

y.majorIntervalLength         =CPTDecimalFromDouble(1.0);
y.majorTickLineStyle          = nil;
y.minorTicksPerInterval       = 0;
y.minorTickLineStyle          = nil;
y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromInteger(0);
y.hidden = YES;

[self.graph reloadData];

}

    -(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
    {
        if ( fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldX ) {
    return [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInteger:(NSInteger)index-1];
}
else if ( fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldY ) {

    return [NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:[[closeTicks objectAtIndex:index] doubleValue]];
}
    }

    -(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
     {
   return closeTicks.count;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the axis labeling properties before setting the plot ranges on the plot space. It's possible that something is triggering the creation of the default labels one unit apart along each axis before you turn them off. If there are a lot of labels (the x-axis alone will have 400—one for each data point), it can take a long time to relabel the axis.

Comment: No change. I shifted the range configuration to the bottom (right before reloadData is called) and the graph still takes forever to actually show up in the view. The delegate method didFinishDrawing is called when it does finally show up. Are we missing something obvious here??

Comment: Seems to hang up right before calling renderAsVectorInContext

Comment: Core Animation calls `-drawInContext:` which in turn calls `-renderAsVectorInContext:` for each drawing cycle. Is your app doing anything that might block the main thread and hold up the drawing cycle? Are all Core Plot methods being called from the main thread?

Comment: Yes coreplot is being called from main. Some reactive cocoa and a bit of UI updating seems to be the main threads main concerns. Would it be better to push coreplot to the background? Or my other code? Is there a way to set up coreplot in the background then add it to the view when it is finished drawing?

Comment: Fixed it! Had nothing to do with CorePlot! had to change my NSURLConnection from [NSOperationQueue new] to [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]. Finally!